# Difference between these two stringstreams?

Tags: c++, stringstream

Is there any difference between this:

```cpp
stringstream read(s);
```

and this?

```cpp
stringstream read;
read << s;
```

Does it matter?

Comment: Quite a bit of difference in the unlikely event that `s` is not a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the reference for stringstream http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/

You can see that your first piece of code is calling the stringstream constructor, which accepts a const string reference.  The underlying buffer is constructed from that string.  Other data types will not work here.

Your second piece of code uses the insertion operator which is inherited from ostream and acts the same as it does for cout.

You can use the insertion operator to add different types to the stringstream buffer like ints for example, but you can only pass strings to the constructor.